# 'monotone in (x,y)' vs 'monotone in x and y'

Tags: calculus, notation

What's the difference between function being 'monotone in (x,y)' and 'monotone in x and y'? Or they denote the same?

Comment: In what context did you find the expression 'monotone in $(x,y)$'?

Comment: Not sure I ever did. The inspiration for this question comes from the existence of functions that are 'continuous in x and y' but fail to be 'continuous in (x,y)'.